# HDF5 Output Error with Parallel Programming in Python (HDF5: infinite loop closing library)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to parallelize my python code with MPI. I'm reading in my input from a txt file and writing the output in an HDF5 file. When I submit my job to the queue (just one node, 32ppn), I get the following error when I opening the output hdf5 file($ h5dump groups_25x25x25.hdf5):

"h5dump error: internal error (file h5dump.c:line 1615)
HDF5: infinite loop closing library
     D,G,T,F,FD,P,FD,P,FD,P,E,E,SL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL"

When I run the program from my home directory (mpiexec-l -n 4 python find_bounded_v2.py), I get this error: h5dump error: internal error (file h5dump.c:line 1615)

I checked my run.log and the program is running fine, so it probably has to do with the input/output.

Here is the part of the code where I modify i/o and might be the source of the error:

```
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

[SOME OTHER STUFF]
numbounded= np.zeros (1)
totalbounded= np.zeros(1)

f= h5py.File ("groups_25x25x25.hdf5", "w")
bh = f.create_group ("bounded_neighbors") 

for k in range(local_start, local_end):
    target = ids[k]
    bound_ids=Energy
(target_halo,np.array(mvir),np.array(x),np.array(y),np.array(z),np.array(vx),np.array(vy),np.array(vz),np.array (ids))
    bh.create_dataset(str(target), data= bound_ids)
    numbounded[0]+= len (bound_ids)

comm.Allreduce(numbounded,totalbounded, op = MPI.SUM)
[SOME OTHER STUFF]
f.close()
```

All my log file looks fine, but the output file just isn't working as I keep getting the above error. I'm new to MPI, so any suggestions for fixes would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you fill in some of the blanks there so that we have a reproducible test case?

Comment: In reading the [python parallel HDF5 example](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/mpi.html) don't you need to open the file with the mpiio driver and specify a communicator? `f = h5py.File('parallel_test.hdf5', 'w', driver='mpio', comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD)`